# c++ generic solution for alternating for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I want something done for every second run of a for-loop. Is there a nice way to do this without using tons of lines?

And while we're at it, I would prefer a generic "trick", so doing something every third or forth time is possible as well?

Example:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
   do something;

   if( i == odd number )
   {
      do something every alternating time;
   }
}
```

Hope you can help.
Cheers.

Comment: This is one solution.  The other is to unroll the loop, and use `i += 2` to increment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do something every n-th time:

```
if (i % n == 0) …
```

Note that this will trigger on the first, the n+1-th, the 2n+1-th, etc. iterations. If you want to trigger on the nth, 2n-th, etc., do this:

```
if (i % n == n - 1) …
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (i % 2)
```

is true for odd number `i`, false otherwise. If you prefer, you can compare with `1` explicitly:

```
if (i % 2 == 1)
```

Doing something `n` times is similar. For instance, every 4 times, starting from `1`

```
if (i % 4 == 1)
```